# Navigation Controller back button is not releasing memory of dismissed viewController

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

Newbie question here. 
Imagine a very basic storyboard with 2 vc (A and B). 
A is embedded in a navController. A has a collectionView showing a grid of images. B is displaying the clicked grid item in big. So simple list->detail.

Doing all with IB, I ctrl-dragged from collectionView cell item to B and selected 'show (e.g Push)' segue.

Now when I run the app and click multiple times on image in grid and then on '< Back' button, I explore the memory graph. 
I can see 10 'B' view controllers if I did the navigation 10 times.

That causes a lot of memory to be used and it grows every time.

I found a few posts speaking about unwind, and pop to root vc, but all are dealing with programmatic navigation. Here's just the case of simple storyboard done all with IB.

**Expected**: A->B->A. Memory: A

**Reality**: A->B->A. Memory: A, B

How can I avoid retaining the memory for those vc that are dismissed?

in A I have:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "dreamDetail" {
        let newViewController = segue.destination as! DreamDetailViewController
        newViewController.dream = allDreams?[(collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first?.item)!]
        newViewController.dreams = allDreams
    }
}
```

in B I have:

```
weak var dream: DreamRealm?{
    didSet {
    }
}

var dreams: [DreamRealm]?{
    didSet {
    }
}
```

DreamRealm is just a Realm model.

```
class DreamRealm: Object {

@objc dynamic var filename: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var path = ""
```

Comment: is there a strong reference between A->B and B->A somewhere else in your code?

Comment: how you are navigating to A from B?

Comment: @ReinierMelian as I said in description, just by pressing back button on nav controller. No custom code.

Comment: @TusharSharma looks like yes. But I've just profiled the app with Instruments/Leaks tool and it displays all green checks while doing that navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid retaining the memory for your VC that are dismissed, you need to check if there is any retain cycle.

One step to help you to check if your VCs are correctly deinitialised, you can implement a method called `deinit`. It's a method called when your VC is deinit and no longer in the memory. You can print a message to see if it's the case or not.

If it's not the case, you probably have a strong reference somewhere in your code. You need to avoid it by weakening your reference with `weak` keyword or `unowned` or just delete it if you don't need it.

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue on new project and deinit gets called.
However on my app it's not. Then there might be a strong ref. 
I don't understand though why Instruments/Leaks shows all green checks..

Comment: When navigating A to B I'm "passing" 2 objects in prepareForSegue. 1 is 
 a custom class. And the other is an array of custom classes. The first I can make weak, but the latter I can't 'may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not..'

Comment: Can you post some code for you prepareForSegue ? It will help us to identify the issue and to help you. Also the code for your custom classes.

Comment: I've just found the issue. Looks like the cause is ImageSlideshow pod. https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow. Because when I comment out all the references to that, I have the print method in deninit called.
https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow/issues/154

Comment: Good job ! Sometimes an external API has strange behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

1. All IB connections with UI elements(in view controller) must be `weak`!
2. Try to release `strong` objects in `dealloc` method;

Sometimes there are some delay before garbage collector deallocate objects,  do "show" and "back", wait ~10 seconds and see if more memory are released.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @Arrabidas92's answer:

- watch out for double nested blocks

I built a retain cycle with the following code:

```
navigationItem.reactive.rightBarButtonItems <~ user.producer.map{ $0
    .map{ [weak self] user in
        guard let self = self else { return [] }
```

I thought, that the `[weak self]` of the inner map would suffice. It does not. The outer map already captures self (to pass it to the inner?). My retain cycle went away after writing `user.producer.map{ [weak self] $0`.